# SharedPreferences not saving without restarting app

Tags: java, android, eclipse

What code is used to detect any changes made in SharedPreferences when the app is running?
The changes made in my SharedPreferences are only reflected when the app is closed and started  again. It does not gets changed during the same session.

To fetch the preferences I use the following code
In SettingsActivity.java

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("unit_type"));
    }
```

and in activity.java

```
final SharedPreferences unitpreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
final String unitstring = unitpreference.getString("unit_type", "");
```

But what and where should I write some code so that the changes are made instantly?

Full Updated Code:
SettingsActivity.java

```
package com.basic.mileagecalculatorwithsettings;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceCategory;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.preference.RingtonePreference;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import java.util.List;

public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity 
{

private static final boolean ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS = false;
protected static final String TAG = null;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setupActionBar();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new GeneralPreferenceFragment())
                .commit();
    } else {
        // use normal preferences
        setupSimplePreferencesScreen();

        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(mPrefsListener);
    }
}

SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener mPrefsListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, final String key) {
        if ("unit_type".equals(key)) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Setting has been changed!");
        }
    }

};
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() 
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) 
    {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
}
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        switch (item.getItemId()) 
        {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //setupSimplePreferencesScreen();
    }
    private void setupSimplePreferencesScreen() {
        if (!isSimplePreferences(this)) {
            return;
        }
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);}
    @Override
    public boolean onIsMultiPane() 
    {
        return isXLargeTablet(this) && !isSimplePreferences(this);
    }
    private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) 
    {
        return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
    }
    private static boolean isSimplePreferences(Context context) 
    {
        return ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS
                || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB
                || !isXLargeTablet(context);
    }
    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) 
    {
        if (!isSimplePreferences(this)) 
        {
            //loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
        }
    };
    private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) 
        {
            String stringValue = value.toString();

            if (preference instanceof ListPreference) 
            {
                ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
                int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
                preference.setSummary(index >= 0 ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]:null);
            }
            else if (preference instanceof RingtonePreference) 
            {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(stringValue))
                {
                    //preference.setSummary(R.string.pref_ringtone_silent);
                }
                else 
                {
                    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                            preference.getContext(), Uri.parse(stringValue));
                    if (ringtone == null) 
                    {preference.setSummary(null);}
                    else 
                    {
                        String name = ringtone.getTitle(preference.getContext());
                        preference.setSummary(name);
                    }
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                preference.setSummary(stringValue);
            }
            return true;
        }
};
private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) 
{
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);
    sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext()).getString(preference.getKey(),""));
}
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_list"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("fuel_type"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("unit_type"));

    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


    }
    public void onPause(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      super.onPause();
      addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);

     }
}
}
```

pref_general.xml

```
<ListPreference
    android:defaultValue="1"
    android:entries="@array/pref_example_list_titles"
    android:entryValues="@array/pref_example_list_values"
    android:key="city_list"
    android:negativeButtonText="@null"
    android:positiveButtonText="@null"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_add_friends_to_messages" android:enabled="true"/>

<ListPreference
    android:defaultValue="1"
    android:entries="@array/pref_fuel_type_titles"
    android:entryValues="@array/pref_fuel_type_values"
    android:key="fuel_type"
    android:negativeButtonText="@null"
    android:positiveButtonText="@null"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_select_fuel" android:enabled="true"/>

<ListPreference
    android:defaultValue="1"
    android:entries="@array/pref_units_titles"
    android:entryValues="@array/pref_units_values"
    android:key="unit_type"
    android:negativeButtonText="@null"
    android:positiveButtonText="@null"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_unit" android:enabled="true"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: you have to commit your Shared Preferences

Comment: Where and what should I type? I couldn't get it to work.
Can you please look at my code here,
http://pastebin.com/QBCQw2sV

Comment: Have You tried  to set SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html

Comment: yes, I have used it, please check my paste.

Comment: Please, provide Your code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked Your code and looks like You're not creating `GeneralPreferenceFragment` at all. So, if I add the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setupActionBar();

    // Display the fragment as the main content.
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new GeneralPreferenceFragment())
            .commit();
}
```

And remove `setupSimplePreferencesScreen()` call, then it works fine on latest Android versions.

If You need to support old versions, I would do it the following way:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    private static final boolean ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS = false;
    protected static final String TAG = null;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setupActionBar();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Display the fragment as the main content.
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(android.R.id.content, new GeneralPreferenceFragment())
                    .commit();
        } else {
            // use normal preferences
            setupSimplePreferencesScreen();

            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(mPrefsListener);
        }
    }

    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener mPrefsListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, final String key) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Setting has been changed!");
        }
    };

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setupActionBar()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case android.R.id.home:
                //NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //setupSimplePreferencesScreen();
    }
    private void setupSimplePreferencesScreen() {
        if (!isSimplePreferences(this)) {
            return;
        }
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
        return isXLargeTablet(this) && !isSimplePreferences(this);
    }

    private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
        return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
    }
    private static boolean isSimplePreferences(Context context) {
        return ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS
                || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB
                || !isXLargeTablet(context);
    }

    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        if (!isSimplePreferences(this)) {
            //loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
        }
    }

    private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Setting has been changed!");

            String stringValue = value.toString();

            if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
                ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
                int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
                preference.setSummary(index >= 0 ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]:null);
            }
            else if (preference instanceof RingtonePreference) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(stringValue)) {
                    //preference.setSummary(R.string.pref_ringtone_silent);
                } else {
                    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                            preference.getContext(), Uri.parse(stringValue));
                    if (ringtone == null) {
                        preference.setSummary(null);
                    } else {
                        String name = ringtone.getTitle(preference.getContext());
                        preference.setSummary(name);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                preference.setSummary(stringValue);
            }

            return true;
        }
    };
    private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference){
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);
        sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext()).getString(preference.getKey(),""));
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_list"));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("fuel_type"));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("unit_type"));
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
        }

        public void onPause(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onPause();
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
        }
    }
}
```

I've checked that code with the following pref_general.xml:

```
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Title category">

        <ListPreference
            android:key="example_list"
            android:title="example_list"
            android:summary="example_list"
            android:entries="@array/entries_list_preference"
            android:entryValues="@array/entryvalues_list_preference"
            android:dialogTitle="example_list" />
        <ListPreference
            android:key="fuel_type"
            android:title="fuel_type"
            android:summary="fuel_type"
            android:entries="@array/entries_list_preference"
            android:entryValues="@array/entryvalues_list_preference"
            android:dialogTitle="fuel_type" />
        <ListPreference
            android:key="unit_type"
            android:title="unit_type"
            android:summary="unit_type"
            android:entries="@array/entries_list_preference"
            android:entryValues="@array/entryvalues_list_preference"
            android:dialogTitle="unit_type" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

And was able to observe `Setting has been changed!` logs.

Basically the issue with Your code was that You're neither create `GeneralPreferenceFragment` which has listeners neither use `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`. I would suggest to make code more readable, then it might be easier for You to spot issues.

Comment: I've slightly corrected it. I've tried it (wiht Your code from paste) and it worked fine, brakepoint in listeners were triggered. Please try it before posting. And also, please provide Your code in the question instead of pastebin.

Comment: No, but I would appreciate it if You could update Your question with the code You've just tried. So I'll be able to check it.

Comment: Do you know how to do that? What should I type in onResume() ?

Comment: Finally Got it to work!! ThankYou so much for your help! It was very kind of you!
I have had added the update view code in onCreate, I just had to place it in onResume!

Comment: You're welcome. I would appreciate it if You could clean up comments in this question, because there's no information about the question/probkem itself.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a problem that the `SharedPreferences` are not saved until you close your app you probably did not commit/apply the changes (As user1283633 suggest in his/her comment).

From the JavaDoc for [SharedPrecerences.Editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html):

> Interface used for modifying values in a SharedPreferences object. All
>   changes you make in an editor are batched, and not copied back to the
>   original SharedPreferences until you call commit() or apply()

I assume you use the `SharedPreferences.Editor` when adding data to your `SharedPreferences` store, and after you are done adding data you could try to call `commit()` or `apply()` on the `Editor`. Pick `commit()` if you care about the result (return boolean), otherwise you could go with `apply()` (void).